# OCR result improvement

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

I am using tesseract dll with .NET application. In this where there are data in tables and and lines coming in image the text extracted are not accurate. The accuracy is too low. I tried all possible combinatins. How to improve this?

I tried PageSegMode and EngineMode all possible combination but the result are not appropriate. I am looking for improved accuracy. Also if any other open source tool available.

Comment: OCR is no "always 100%" technology. You can try different engines with different models and you can try post-recognition touch-up ... hard to say anything without seeing what we are actually dealing with, here.